# JS - why does this Codewars challenge return undefined for one test while 104 other tests pass?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I'm solving the [Highest Scoring Word](https://www.codewars.com/kata/highest-scoring-word/train/javascript) challenge on Codewars, which states -

> Given a string of words (x), you need to find the highest scoring
>   word.
>
> Each letter of a word scores points according to it's position in the
>   alphabet. a=1, z=26 and everything inbetween.
>
> You need to return the highest scoring word as a string.
>
> If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in
>   the original string.
>
> All letters will be lower case and all inputs will be valid.

My approach to the problem is as follows -

1. Construct an object, that maps alphabets to their corresponding integer values, like `a - 1`, `b - 2`, etc.
2. Split the input string on spaces, for each word - find it's score by-

   - creating an array of the word's letters
   - map over the array to get score of each letter
   - reduce this array with addition and get the total score of the word
3. The array returned in step 2 will have scores for each word in the original string. Find the maximum value in this array and get it's position, return the word from the original string at that particular position.

   My code snippet (demo [here](https://jsbin.com/vucovuy/edit?js,console) ) -

```js
function high(x) {
  let myObj = {};
  for (let i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
    myObj[String.fromCharCode(i + 96)] = i;
  }
  // console.log(myObj);

  let scores = x.split(' ').map(word => [...word].map(a => myObj[a]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

  return x.split(' ')[scores.indexOf(Math.max(...scores))];
}

console.log(high('take me to semynak'))
```

When I run this in codewars, the results show 104 passed tests, 1 failed, and 1 error. The only info. about the failures/errors shown is -

> Expected: 'bintang', instead got: undefined

Since the actual input for this test case is not shown, this info. by itself is not very useful.

I tried to think of some edge cases, like two words having the same score, but even then `.indexOf()` should return the position of the earlier value, as you can see in this example -

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 3];
console.log(nums.indexOf(Math.max(...nums)));
```

Here's the screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Try to trim the string first and split by regex / +/ instead of just a single space.

Comment: A quick test on the online site tells me that the "bintang" test case contains the string "12", for which your map doesn't have a value. `map(a => myObj[a] || 0)` will fix this.

Comment: @MOehm, that contradicts *"All letters will be lower case and all inputs will be valid."*

Comment: @NinaScholz: Look, _I_ haven't written the test cases. If you just return the input string, you will see that one of the strings is "take 12 bintang and a dance please". I'm not going to defend the tests here, but all letters are lower case and it can be argued that a valid input just means that the input is a string (and not a number or `null` or whatever), not that the words can contain only letters.

Comment: @MOehm, it was not a personal question, but rather wondering.

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry if I got too defensive here.

Answer (score 2):

The statement of the problem says that the words will consist of lowercase letters only, but it doesn't guarantee that the input string will contain only words and spaces.

In order to account for punctuation, numbers and other non-words, you need to extract all sequences of lowercase letters as words (instead of splitting the input string on spaces only).

```js
function high(x) {
    let words = x.split(/[^a-z]+/);
    let scores = words.map(word => [...word].map(a => a.charCodeAt(0) - 96).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
    return words[scores.indexOf(Math.max(...scores))];
}
    
console.log(high('today is 24 august, 2017'));
```